# Change SQL Result Text Size in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

There does not seem to be a setting in Tools>Options>Fonts and Colors to change the Message tab font for SQL Query error result.

Can't seem to change the message font.

Assumed it was the SQL Results - Text option in Fonts and Colors but that has no affect on the font size.

[image: Visual Studio SQL Window]

Comment: SQL Results - Text option in Fonts and Colors worked for me but I had to restart VS2022 to see the change.